# Install Psycopg2 failed. error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

I can't install Psychopg2 in my django project after changing the computer.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is saying that you don't have gcc installed. You must install gcc on your system first.

You can also install psycopg2-binary instead, which is probably easier. That will not require the gcc compiler.

Comment: pip install psycopg2-binary installed installed successfully but it doesn't help

Comment: I'm glad it did. In any case the documentation recommends that production use of psycopg2 use the version that is built from source. So you have the best solution. I am about to move some Django code I've been testing to Postgresql, so I'm glad you asked.